# Automatic snapshots won't run on BackupExec CPS 2010

Tags: snapshot, vss, backupexec

I am running Symantec BackupExec CPS 2010 on Server 2008 R2.  I have everything set up ok, the backups are running and I can perform restores.  I also have configured the snapshots, but they do not run according to the schedule.  I can, however, manually run the snapshots through CPS without any error, but when I look to restore something I do not see any of the snapshot restore points.  I can see something that appears relevant in the CPS logs:

```
[RPCc] RxCsAdminSnapshotWrapper:d096274b-d79f-11df-a54f-001517b02006 failed with error code 0
```

I also sometimes see:

```
HLS703E Folder failed for CRXTreeIterator::InternalDoShortCut -- RXRESULT_IllegalOperation: HLS739E (InternalDoShortCut) Problem in shorthand notation 'F:' -- Not a shortcut
```

I see the latter error more often in the log (not just when the snapshots should run), and F is the drive where the CPS backups are located, but the normal backups all run fine.  Through the Windows shadow copy interface, I have set the F drive snapshots to be stored on a different, larger drive, but the snapshots didn't work even before I made that change.  Has anyone worked with CPS 2010 and seen an issue like this before?

UPDATE: I have also found that if I go into the Shadow Copies tab for the drive I'm working with (or vssuirun), I am not able to Enable and set a Schedule for the Shadow Copies (this would be outside of BackupExec).  I get this error:

```
Failed to create a default schedule for creating shadow copies of volume F:\.
Error 0x80070005: Access is denied.
```

I believe this might be related to this issue if BackupExec relies on the Windows Shadow Copy scheduling for its own scheduling.  Hopefully this might help someone see what issue  I might be experiencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after playing around with it for a while longer, I found the problem.  It turned out to be the permissions on C:\Windows\Tasks.  Even the Administrators group only had read access, so this caused the error when trying to set the default schedule (ie, create a new task).  It turns out that CPS does work directly with the Windows Shadow Copies, so it was trying to create a new task, but wasn't giving me any error about it.  After fixing the permissions, everything worked normally.